# Set thumbnail with an image URL in Wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm currently just experimenting with wordpress PHP functions. There is a thing I don't understand. I made a plugin which gets photos in URL format, then puts them in a shortcode which just pastes the individual photo to Wordpress posts. How should I make a shortcode which would just set the thumbnail for the specific post it was posted to?
bit of source code:

```
function fone(){
    global $images;
    return ($images[0]);
} 
add_shortcode( 'one', 'fone');
```

tried searching about set_post_thumbnail(), but it needs a thumbnail ID which I don't have. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You should check this function:

```
media_sideload_image($url, $post_id=0, $desc='', $return='html');
```